# Calculating value in CustomTableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have three fields `txtValue1`, `txtValue2` and `txtValue3` in `CustomTableCell`.
Now I want to multiply value of `txtValue1`(**UITextfield**) and `txtValue2`(**UILabel**) and display result in `txtValue3`(**UILabel**).
 I've tried method in `cellforRowAtIndexPath` using `Double`, but it returns with empty.
 How can I fix it? Thanks for any help.

//UPDATED//

Here, I am getting txtValue1 and txtValue2 from webservice. But I want to show result value in txtVale3 by calculating them. **I am using customTableviewcell**. e.g I want total.txt by multiplying quantity.txt and price.txt. I hope you all understand.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: please share some code, how you are multiplying and displaying using your labels and textviews.

Comment: Please share your code with us. It will be easy for us to help you...

Comment: Do you have value of txtValue1 and txtValue2(are you getting values) or you enter it at runtime?

Comment: You need to get enter value of txtvalue1 and txtvalue2 and multiply those value ans save result in one one nsinteger

Comment: @Mital. See updated Que. I already have both value for txt1 & txt2.

Comment: Please post your code to help it out

Comment: txtValue1 or txtValue2 is editable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `tag` for `UITextField` say `97 and UILabel say 98 and 99` respectively in a cell.

Now use `delegate` method of `UITextField` to do `multiply operation`.

```
 - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{
  UITableView *cell = (UITableView *)[tbView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[tbView indexPathForRowAtPoint:textField.superview.frame.origin]];
  if (cell) {
     UITextField *txtField1 = (UITextField *)(cell viewWithTag:97);
     UILabel *lbl1 = (UILabel *)(cell viewWithTag:98);
     UILabel *lbl2 = (UILabel *)(cell viewWithTag:99);

    if(txtField1)
    {
       int value1 = [txtField1.text intValue];
       int value2 = [lbl1.text intValue];
       int value3 = value1 * value2
       lbl2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",value3];
    }
  }    
}
```

**EDIT** : edited according to question

Comment: he is using one text field and two label so adjust your answer

Answer (score 1):

apply like this when  you get result of webservice ,

```
text1.text= text1value
text2.text=text2value
text3.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",([text1value intValue] * [text2value intValue])];
```

and do the table reload.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the first and second value, (as you are showing it in `tableView` so I assume these are more than one), prepare a array like this:

```
- (NSArray *) getArrayToLoadDataInTableView : (NSArray *) valueFromWebService {
    //load value from web service in `valueFromWebService` array in form of dictionary like MENTIONED BELOW or however convinient to you
    /*NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"2", @"firstOprand",
                                @"2", @"secondOprand", nil];*/

    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in valueFromWebService) {
        NSMutableDictionary *finalDict = [dictionary mutableCopy];
        int result = [[finalDict valueForKey:@"firstOprand"] intValue] * [[finalDict valueForKey:@"secondOprand"] intValue];
        [finalDict setObject:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:result] stringValue] forKey:@"result"];
        [array addObject:finalDict];
    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:array];
}
```

Now you can load data in your `tableView` from this array return from this method.